# Compare file online without downloading with bash wget

Tags: bash, wget

I need to compare a local files to files hosted on a URL and if the 2 files being compared are different, then I want to replace the local one. Whats the best way to do this? I know I can use `wget` to download the files and then do the comparison with `diff`. Is there a non-redundant way of doing this...i.e. only do `wget` if the file is different.

Comment: There is `wget -N`, which will check the modification time header and only download if the remote file is newer. Depending on the server's behaviour though, that header might or might not be accurate, or even present at all.

Comment: Why not use something like rsync that will handle it all for you?

Comment: another option: zsync http://zsync.moria.org.uk/.